# Kernel restart when setting x_lim matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I am drawing a scatter plot using Matplotlib on IPython notebook.

When I limit my x axis from 0 to 6e7 I get Kernel restart error.

What shall I do?

Here's the code which I using to limit the x axis:

```
ax.set_xlim(0, 6e7)
```

Without the above line everything is working fine.

The reason I want to limit the x axis is that I want to have many plots from different data and able to compare them. Therefore I want my different plots to have same axis.

---

**UPDATE**

I just noticed that even if I limit my x axis from 0 to 100, I am getting the same error.

---

**Additional information**

*Error message*: The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

*Code snippet I am using*:

[image]

The line which I have commented above is causing the problem.

*IPython version*: 4.0.1

*Matplotlib version*: 1.5.0

Comment: Things you can do now: Break the program down to the simplest program possible that reproduces this issue. Post this code here. check `matplotlib.__version__`, and give us that as well. Start IPython notebook directly from a shell. Provoke said kernel crash, then check the shell for messages. Post relevant error messages here.

Comment: Does it work if you run it as a script from the console?

Comment: @MikeMüller I have no idea how to do that. Shall I try?

Comment: try with `%matplotlib notebook` instead of `%matplotlib inline`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be due to IPython Notebook limitations. For debugging:

1. Copy all your relevant code into a file.
2. Add `plt.show()` at the end of the file.
3. Save this file as `myfile.py`.
4. Run it from the console: `python myfile.py`.
5. See if it works our you get an error message.

Comment: Looks like an IPython Notebook problem. Likely a bug. Can you try on different machine? As a workaround you can at least use your script version for now.

Comment: Is there an error message on the console the IPython Notebook server runs on?

Comment: It says: `[I 10:06:54.055 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
WARNING:root:kernel c8025ce1-2f16-464d-a72a-2c4b65a489d1 restarted`

Comment: One more thing: If I remove the last two lines and use limit the x axis, then it works on the notebook.